# How to deal with multi-modality?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following data set in the form of {id, sample#, zone}:
[(1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5), (3, 2, 2), (4, 1, 2)]

The following code:

```
cur.execute("SELECT zone FROM zone_temp GROUP BY zone HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM(SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM zone_temp GROUP BY zone) tmp)")
```

or:

```
cur.execute("SELECT zone FROM zone_temp GROUP BY zone ORDER BY COUNT(zone)")
```

returns only the first value that occurs the most (5).  In this data set 5 and 2 are equally frequent and as such there really isn't a "most frequent" value.  What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: That depends on the meaning of the data, and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Option 1) If more than 1 mode exists return "NO MODE"  Option 2) If more than 2 modes exist return "NO MODE", else list each mode.